# How to prevent Mouse Scroll in ToolStripComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, mousewheel, toolstripcombobox

I am trying to disable Mouse Scroll in my ToolStripComboBox, I thought I can catch the Mouse Wheel event, but while the event is available for ComboBox, it is not available instead for the ToolStripComboBox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToolStripComboBox` helpfully exposes its underlying `ComboBox` control in its aptly named [`ComboBox` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox.combobox.aspx). This allows us to access its properties, methods, and events that were not been wrapped into the `ToolStripComboBox`.

And, as you probably know, the standard `ComboBox` control exposes a [`MouseWheel` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel.aspx) that fires each time the mouse wheel is scrolled while the combo box has focus.

**Putting these two things together, we can add a handler for the `ToolStripComboBox` control's underlying `ComboBox` control's `MouseWheel` event, and override its default behavior.**

So, assuming you have a form that contains a `ToolStrip` and a `ToolStripComboBox`, you can use something like the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      //Attach a handler for the MouseWheel event
      ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(ToolStripComboBox_MouseWheel);
   }

   private void ToolStripComboBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
      //Cast the MouseEventArgs to HandledMouseEventArgs
      HandledMouseEventArgs mwe = (HandledMouseEventArgs)e;

      //Indicate that this event was handled
      //(prevents the event from being sent to its parent control)
      mwe.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Alternatively, of course, you could always subclass the existing `ToolStripComboBox` control and override its behavior there in the same way shown above.

Comment: @raz3r: You're welcome; I'm glad I could help. This is a really good question, and a quick Google search doesn't turn up any answers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Cody Gray suggested you may want the wheel scolling to work when the combobox is dropped. Just chech the DroppedDown state in MouseWheel handle:

```
    public class MyToolStripComboBox : ToolStripComboBox
    {
        public MyToolStripComboBox()
        {
            this.ComboBox.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(ComboBox_MouseWheel);
        }

        void ComboBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.ComboBox.DroppedDown)
                ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Scrolling dropped combobox with wheel doesn't change the selection, so it works as expected